# Solve A Second Order D.E. Using The Wronskian.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the following D.E.

$$(1-x^2)y''-xy'+4y=0$$$$(\alpha ^2=4)$$

> Show the following is a solution

$$y=1-2x^2$$

> and then find  a solution satisfying
>   $$y(0)=1, y'(0)=1$$
>   $$y'=-4x$$$$y''=-4$$$$y''-\frac{x}{1-x^2}y'+\frac{4}{1-x^2}y=0$$$$P(x)=\frac{-x}{1-x^2}, Q(x)=\frac{4}{1-x^2}$$$$x=\pm 1$$$$W(x)=e^{-\int p(x)dx}=e^{-\int \frac{xdx}{1-x^2}}$$$$t=x^2, dt=2xdx,\frac{dt}{2}=xdx$$$$W(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{1-t}dt}$$$$W(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{2}\ln {(1-t)}}={(1-t)^{-\frac{1}{2}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$$$y_2(x)=y_1(x)\int \frac{W}{y_1^2}dx=(1-2x^2)\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\frac{1}{(1-2x^2)^2}dx$$$$x=\cos \theta , \sqrt{1-x^2}=\sin \theta $$$$dx=-\sin \theta d\theta $$
>   But where to from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track with the last integral, you just needed to keep going! Let 
$$I\,\equiv\, \int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}\,}\,(1-2x^{2})^{2}}$$
and we shall make the suggested substitution $x=\sin(t)$. You should be able to verify the following relations based upon this substitution:
$$\cos(t)\,=\,\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\;;\quad \cos(2t)\,=\,1-2\sin^{2}(t)\,=\, 1-2x^2\;; \quad dx=\cos(t)\,dt.$$
With these we have
$$I = \int \frac{\cos(t)\;dt}{\cos(t)\cdot \cos^{2}(2t)} \;=\; \int \frac{dt}{\cos^{2}(2t)} \;=\; \frac{1}{2}\tan(2t) + C$$
which is a standard integral you should either know or be able to do yourself. All we are left to do is write everything back in terms of $x$:
$$\tan(2t)\;=\;\frac{\sin(2t)}{\cos(2t)}\;=\;\frac{2\sin(t)\cos(t)}{1-2\sin^{2}(t)} \;=\; \frac{2x\sqrt{1-x^{2}\,}}{1-2x^{2}}$$
using the double angle formula for $\sin,\cos$ and also the relations between $x,t$ given above. Thus

$$I\;=\; \frac{x\sqrt{1-x^{2}\,}}{1-2x^{2}} + C$$

I have left some gaps for you to fill in, but you should now be able to go on and find the solution $y_{2}(x)$ you are looking for.